# Validating XML request in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, xml, laravel, validation

I have an upcoming project that will receive multiple API calls. Some API calls will be in JSON, others in XML. I want to use Laravel's Request Validation (preferably Form Request, if possible) to validate incoming XML.

That said, I have code that will reliably translate an XML structure into a valid plain php array. I'm thinking that might be a good place to start. I was thinking maybe I have some middleware that translates the incoming XML into a php array.

How can I use Laravel's built-in request validation to check the incoming XML request after I have translated the XML into a php array?

Comment: A naive google search reveals a little repo at https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/laravel-xml-middleware which can do what you need. You can then just use the request validation normally as you would use any other request validation according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a package for this myself. If anyone is interested you can find it here:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/request-xml

It includes

- Converting incoming XML into an array and merging it into the request. This way it can be validated.
- Checking if a request is XML.
- Checking if the request wants to receive XML in the response.